# Run code every time an ASP.NET page is loaded?

Tags: asp.net, logging

I have to change an existing Web App to enable User Activity logging.  For the most part, logging every time someone accesses a page is fine.  We've tried extracting the info from the IIS logs but it records the proxy details instead of the user that's logged on.

So then I thought about running code on the Page_Load of every form.  The only problem is that this app consists of about 120 forms.  I tried putting the code in a base class by performing a search/replace to change the inheritance, but then I get hundreds of warnings about member hiding.

Is there another way of accomplishing what I want to do?

Comment: How about adding the logging functionality in void Application_AuthenticateRequest of global.asax?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx You could probably do this by adding your own HttpModule, or as Karthik suggests via global.asax

Answer (score 2):

Add a httpModule to your application. Modules are hit for every request so add your logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add hook up to one of the events, to get around this issue.

However, the order of the events are not guaranteed - e.g. `BasePage.Load` may fire before or after `InheritedPage.Load`.

To be more granular, use the `PreInit`, `Init` etc..

#### Step 1

Do a find/replace for the `System.Web.UI.Page` to `BasePage`

#### Step 2

Add this class to your web project

```
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   // Assuming nlog
   private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

   protected BasePage()
   {
      this.Load += new EventHandler(LogPageLoad);
   }

   protected void LogPageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Logger.Trace("Loading Page: {0}",  this.Title);
   }
}
```